Filter document according to matching array value in mongodb
I have a mongodb collection named students, where there are 3 documents:
{
  _id: ObjectId('66880dd88517a33fd8141e08'),
  name: 'Mark',
  courses: [
    {course_id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1a'), active: true},
    {course_id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1b'), active: false}
  ]
}

{
  _id: ObjectId('668626f11b64d2e86632e7cb'),
  name: 'John',
  courses: [
    {course_id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1a'), active: false},
    {course_id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1b'), active: true}
  ]
}

{
  _id: ObjectId('6684e3b628fcee8f24ead736'),
  name: 'Doe',
  courses: [
    {course_id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1a'), active: true},
    {course_id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1b'), active: true}
  ]
}

I have another collection named courses, where there are 2 documents:
{
  _id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1a'),
  note: 'Course on mongodb.'
}

{
  _id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1b'),
  note: 'Advanced mongodb course.'
}

I want to query on courses collection and get desired document matched by given _id. This document should contain an array named students. In this array each student should contain a courses array where only those courses should reside which have matching course_id with given _id and active: true.
Suppose, given _id is 6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1b. So, my desired output should look like this:
{
  _id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1b'),
  note: 'Advanced mongodb course.',
  students: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId('668626f11b64d2e86632e7cb'),
      name: 'John',
      courses: [
        {course_id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1b'), active: true}
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId('6684e3b628fcee8f24ead736'),
      name: 'Doe',
      courses: [
        {course_id: ObjectId('6684e9c8122ef4d77a9dfd1b'), active: true}
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I am using express, mongodb and mongoose. I tried this query:
app.get('/:id', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const batch = await Course.aggregate([
            {"$match": {"_id": req.params.id}},
            {"$lookup": {
                    "from": "students",
                    "localField": "_id",
                    "foreignField": "courses.course_id",
                    "as": "students"
                }
            }
        ])

        res.send(batch)
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            error: error
        })
    }
})

But this query gives me the output, which you can find in this Mongo playground demo.
This result is not my desired output. How to get my desired output?

"This query doesn't provide me my desired output" - What does it give you? In what way(s) is it different than what you're looking for? Bonus points if you share a link to a mongoplayground that has the correct setup and demonstrates the problem

@user20042973 I have updated my question. Please have a further look.

You can perform the filter in the $lookup pipeline:
const batch = await Course.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": req.params.id
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "students",
      "let": {
        courseId: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$courses",
                    cond: {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            req.params.id,
                            "$$this.course_id"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$this.active",
                            true
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                []
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $set: {
            courses: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$courses",
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        req.params.id,
                        "$$this.course_id"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this.active",
                        true
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "students"
    }
  }
]);

Demo @ Mongo Playground

Your solution includes an student name: 'Mark'. This student should be excluded because he has active: false in the courses object. Please look again in my question to understand my desired output.

Updated answer. Please check.
